# .htaccess direccion con ssl y direcciones amigables

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Estoy intentando que el host apunte con ssl y al mismo tiempo las url de dicho host sean amigables, con el siguiente codigo logro que me redireccione con ssl.

```
# Direcciones con ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?homeworkline.xyz
RewriteRule (.*) https://homeworkline.xyz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?maestro.homeworkline.xyz
RewriteRule (.*) https://maestro.homeworkline.xyz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?alumno.homeworkline.xyz
RewriteRule (.*) https://alumno.homeworkline.xyz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

y con este otro trato de que mis url puedan ser accedidas desde "https://homeworkline.xyz/perfil" en lugar de "https://homeworkline.xyz/perfil.php" pero no logro hacerlo.

```
# Direccion sin terminacion php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 

# Direccion sin terminacion html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Me percate que si quito la redirección ssl del host al que estoy intentando acceder con url amigables si me permite entrar a "https://homeworkline.xyz/perfil" el problema es que asi ya no me redirecciona con ssl y me permite entrar tanto con "http" y "https".

Answer (score 0):

Creo que debes cambiar tus reglas en .htaccess. Yo lo tengo así (Ojo: el orden importa) :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9,-]+)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```